# Variable argument list with ints

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to understand variable argument lists in C++. I have one particular example from Java, that I'm trying to get to work:

```
class FindMax {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(findMax(3, 5, 7));
    }

    public static int findMax(int... n) {
        int largest = n[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n.length; i++)
            largest = (largest > n[i]) ? largest : n[i];

        return largest;
    }
}
```

Luckily for me, I found this very example on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/). I tried running this code (which to some extent even makes sense to me):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int FindMax (int n, ...) {
    int i,val,largest;
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,n);
    largest=va_arg(vl,int);
    for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
        val=va_arg(vl,int);
        largest=(largest>val)?largest:val;
    }
    va_end(vl);
    return largest;
}

int main () {
    printf ("The largest value is: %d\n",FindMax (7, 702,422,631,834,892,104,772));
    printf ("The largest value is: %d\n",FindMax (3, 5, 7));
    return 0;
}
```

**And it works.**

*However*, notice how there is a 7 in the first call to `FindMax`. I tried removing that 7 for the code to look like this:

```
...
int main () {
    printf ("The largest value is: %d\n",FindMax (702,422,631,834,892,104,772));
    printf ("The largest value is: %d\n",FindMax (3, 5, 7));
    return 0;
}
```

And when I run this code I get either very weird numbers (e. g. 1351485333) or segfaults.

What is causing this problem?

I am using

```
g++ (GCC) 10.1.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

with `glibc 2.31-5`.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Avoid the C-style variadic parameters (`...`) at all costs. They are inherently unsafe, as your question shows. C++11 variadic templates are a better alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this loop:

```
for (i=1;i<n;i++)
```

The first `int` that is passed to the function needs to be the number of arguments following it.

So, if you remove the `7` in the first call, the loop expects `702` ints to follow after the first argument. Since there aren't enough arguments, you are accessing invalid memory, which can cause a segfault.

Note that you don't really need the `FindMax` function at all. There is already an algorithm that does this:

```
std::cout << std::max({4, 5, 2, 3});   // prints 5
```

Comment: So I basically have to pass the length of the list as the first example?

Your other example fails for me (I'm actually using a different function not findMax) with cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const int*'

Comment: @writzlpfrimpft in C++11 onward, the [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) algorithm in the `<algorithm>` header has an overload that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as input, which can be created from a brace list like `{4, 5, 2, 3}`. If you are compiling with a pre-C++11 compiler, then `std:::max()` does not accept a whole array/container as input, only 2 values to be compared.